# How to interpret the Reform Programs tab in Prison Architect?

Tags: prison-architect

In Prison Architect, the user can start/stop reform programs via a tab -- see image for details:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/prison-architect/images/5/5e/Programs_Tab.png/revision/latest?cb=20140805153948))</sub>

I understand that each program has a certain capacity, which is shown by the light gray squares. Occupied spots are shown in black. The session times and "ACTIVE" indicators are clear enough.

Beyond these things, how  can I read this tab? In particular:

1. What do the different colored boxes (green, yellow, black) indicate? Prisoner type, concentration, or success estimate?
2. Does the bigger box indicate the session leader (teacher, psychologist, foreman, doctor, etc.)?
3. What do the red lines mean? Why are some longer than others?
4. What does the "Reschedule All Programs" button do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by your points:

> What do the different colored boxes (green, yellow, black) indicate? Prisoner type, concentration, or success estimate?

Black - signed up for the program, yellow - en route (as far as I observed), green - 'in class'. Black *during* session - unable to reach (lockdown/solitary)
Also there's a lighter shaded grey which indicate maximum program capacity. I.e. you have 15 desks in classroom - you will be able to distinguish 15 and 5 extra - for potential increase in classroom capacity.

> Does the bigger box indicate the session leader (teacher, psychologist, foreman, doctor, etc.)?

Exactly like that.

> What do the red lines mean? Why are some longer than others?

Progress since start (% *program* completed). E.g. Parole has 1 session, so It's progress bar will fill up from start of session till end. Multi-lesson programs, like kitchen safety & hygiene will fill up as sessions take place.

> What does the "Reschedule All Programs" button do?

This one is not 100% clear to be, but simple explanation is that the game tries to reschedule the programs automatically to maximize 'employment' - number of prisoners signed up to all programs given your constraints (manually fixed programs, available rooms & staff etc.) - by reshuffling the programs *and* reassigning prisoners between them.

Comment: The red lines have 2 shades of red.  What do those each mean?